# Не получается скомпилировать файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

> ```
> File "C:\Users\Дом\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py",
> line 1  
> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with 
> '\xe4' in file C:\Users\Дом\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py
> on line 1, but no encoding declared; see
> http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
> ```

Что надо сделать, у меня питон 3.8.4 коментарий о кодировке UTF-8 ставил, не помогло?

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()

     
print(Back.CYAN)


des = input('что делаем? (+;-;*;/):')

print(Back.GREEN)
a = float(input('number 1:'))
b = float(input('number 2:'))

if des == "+":
    c=a+b
    print(c)
elif des == "-":
    c=a-b
    print(c)
elif des == "*":
    c=a*b
    print(c)
elif des =="/":
    c=a/b
    print(c)
input()
```

Comment: не компилировать интерпретируемый ЯП

Comment: Нужен код, добавь его в вопрос. Скорее всего приходит не UTF-8 символ и Python не может его обработать.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала стоило бы перейти по ссылке из сообщения об ошибке и прочитать. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Сделай первой строкой файла комментарий (или второй если в первой hashbang):

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
```

Если файл не в utf8, укажи соответствующую кодировку.

Или сохрани файл в utf8 с [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).